# In Rails how to create a new line on text being displayed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a client that it putting in data into a text field that needs to be separated into a new line after a certain character. Basically they are giving me this:

```
7:30 AM - 5:00 PM (M-F) 7:30 AM - 12 PM (Sat)
```

I'm displaying it in the view as:

```
<% @region.locations.each do |location| %>
  <%= location.hours_operation %>
<% end %>
```

What I really need is after to a line break after the ")" or before the number. How do I create the line break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split your string with a regular expression that catches the space between your first parenthesis and the AM hour right after it and then join it with "\". Or also use gsub for that:

```
str = '7:30 AM - 5:00 PM (M-F) 7:30 AM - 12 PM (Sat)'

puts str.split(/(?<=\) )/).join("\n")
# 7:30 AM - 5:00 PM (M-F) 
# 7:30 AM - 12 PM (Sat)

puts str.gsub(/(?<=\) )/, "\n")
# 7:30 AM - 5:00 PM (M-F) 
# 7:30 AM - 12 PM (Sat)
```